# use image in php with sql code

Tags: image

i use this code to load image via php and it works ok

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("generator/sample/8120.jpg");
$yellow = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
$font_path = 'generator/fonts/' . $font;
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
 imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 205, 260, $yellow, $font_path, $msg);
```

when i try to add any sql code 
or even include config i get error image can not display

```
include('config.php');
```

my config file works well with other files and any code of sql will work fine 
but the problem image can not display

how can i display the image with sql code ???

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. SQL isn't for displaying images. I am taking a wild guess and I suppose that once you add extra code, your output is no longer a valid image, because it contains extra text/data, other than binary image data.

Comment: how can i put extra output and display image ??

Comment: Where is your output going? what is calling this script? what's the full code for your script? I don't see any output from the snippet.

Comment: <iframe> to display the image in other page